# MYSQL having common record in group by

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

This is my table:

```
user     presenter   price  
------  ------------  --------
84            84      5000
88            84      3000
89            84      4000
89            84      7000
```

I am going to group this table  by `user` and sum up total `price` for each user ,also include the rows that their `presenter` id is equal to `user`
the final result should be :

```
user          total_price  
------    ------------------
84        5000 + 3000 + 4000 + 7000
88        3000
89        4000 + 7000
```

Comment: You have no PK here, which may prove problematic in due course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` for this:

```
SELECT user, SUM(price) AS total_price
FROM (
  SELECT user, price
  FROM mytable

  UNION ALL

  SELECT presenter AS user, price
  FROM mytable AS t1
  WHERE presenter <> user AND
        EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM mytable AS t2
                WHERE t1.presenter = t2.user)) AS t
GROUP BY user
```

The second query appends to `user` data all records having a `presenter` that is also a `user`. The outer query just uses `GROUP BY`, in order to calculate `SUM` of `price` per `user`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bd6932/1)

Comment: wouldn't that select `5000` twice for `84`?

Comment: @OzgurBar yes - but the requirement is unclear. I've presented an alternative version - which relies on prices being unique.

Comment: oh, okay. was kinda curious:]

Answer (score 2):

This solution makes a grave assumption about your data set, which could easily be false (and probably is!)...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,user INT NOT NULL
,presenter INT NOT NULL
,price  INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (user,presenter,price) VALUES
(84,84,5000),
(88,84,3000),
(89,84,4000),
(89,84,7000);

SELECT user
     , GROUP_CONCAT(price) prices
     , SUM(price) total 
  FROM 
     ( SELECT user
            , price 
         FROM my_table
        UNION
       SELECT presenter
            , price 
         FROM my_table
     ) x 
 GROUP 
    BY user;
+------+---------------------+-------+
| user | prices              | total |
+------+---------------------+-------+
|   84 | 5000,3000,4000,7000 | 19000 |
|   88 | 3000                |  3000 |
|   89 | 4000,7000           | 11000 |
+------+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: +1 for both answers. I enjoy seeing the different perspectives and I think it's very educational. I would have posted something similar to your answer but you guys are too fast:] cheers!